# use row as variable with python and sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, string, python-3.x

I am trying to update some values into a database. The user can give the row that should be changed. The input from the user, however is a string. When I try to parse this into the MySQL connector with python it gives an error because of the apostrophes. The code I have so far is:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector
conn = connector.connect(user=dbUser, password=dbPasswd, host=dbHost, database=dbName)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""UPDATE Search SET %s = %s WHERE searchID = %s""", ('maxPrice', 300, 10,))
```

I get this error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''maxPrice' = 300 WHERE searchID = 10' at line 1
```

How do I get rid of the apostrophes? Because I think they are causing problems.

Comment: A column name is not a parameter. Put the column name `maxPrice` directly into your query.

Comment: I want to make the column a parameter. Is this possible? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you can't prepare it using a field.

Perhaps the safest way is to allow only those fields that are expected, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=os.environ.get('USER'),
                               host='localhost',
                               database='sandbox',
                               unix_socket='/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')

cur = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
query = """SELECT column_name
           FROM information_schema.columns
           WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
           AND table_name = 'Search'
        """

cur.execute(query)
fields = [x['column_name'] for x in cur.fetchall()]

user_input = ['maxPrice', 300, 10]

if user_input[0] in fields:
    cur.execute("""UPDATE Search SET {0} = {1} WHERE id = {1}""".format(user_input[0], '%s'),
                tuple(user_input[1:]))

print cur.statement
```

Prints:

```
UPDATE Search SET maxPrice = 300 WHERE id = 10
```

Where:

```
mysql> show create table Search\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Search
CREATE TABLE `Search` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxPrice` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1):

A column name is not a parameter. Put the column name `maxPrice` directly into your SQL.

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE Search SET maxPrice = %s WHERE searchID = %s""", (300, 10))
```

If you want to use the same code with different column names, you would have to modify the string itself.

```
sql = "UPDATE Search SET {} = %s WHERE searchID = %s".format('maxPrice')
cursor.execute(sql, (300,10))
```

But bear in mind that this is not safe from injection the way parameters are, so make sure your column name is not a user-input string or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it like that. You need to place the column name in the string before you call `cursor.execute`. Column names cannot be used when transforming variables in `cursor.execute`.

Something like this would work:

```
sql = "UPDATE Search SET {} = %s WHERE searchID = %s".format('maxPrice')

cursor.execute(sql, (300, 10,))
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically bind object (e.g., column) names, only values. If that's the logic you're trying to achieve, you'd have to resort to string manipulation/formatting (with all the risks of SQL-injection attacks that come with it). E.g.:

```
sql = """UPDATE Search SET {} = %s WHERE searchID = %s""".format('maxPrice')
cursor.execute(sql, (300, 10,))
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I am indeed worried about the SQL-injection, but I guess I have no other choice...

Comment: @JoostLuijben see my answer to allow only valid fields 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039356/263671